# Icinga-web does not update when icinga2 configuration is updated

Tags: icinga

I recently setup a new Icinga2+ Icinga-web server.

Adding services in Icinga2 does cause them to show up in icinga-web, but upon renaming, or deleting any services in icinga2, icinga-web does not remove the old service.

For example, renaming a service called "disk usage" to "disk space usage" and restarting icinga2 will create to services in icinga-web - "disk space usage" and "disk usage".

I have found that this is an issue in the IDO database - truncating the icinga_services table seems to refresh the entries properly. Doing a SELECT on the table, the old service and the new service are both shown as entries, so I assume it is an issue with how icinga2 updates the IDO database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upgrade to Icinga Web 1.11.x - previous version had an issue with showing objects being marked as is_active=0

Comment: Looks like its all working now. -Thanks!